# Omniauth Cucumber Testing - Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, omniauth

I am trying to test my Facebook login button in Cucumber. I am using Omniauth.

Here is what I have in `/features/support/env.rb`

```
Before do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {
    provider: 'facebook',
    uid: '1259910065',
    info: {
      name: 'Test Name',
      email: 'test@example.com'
    }
  })
end

After do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = false
end
```

However, when I try to access `/auth/facebook` in the tests, I get:

```
No route matches [GET] "/auth/facebook" (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

Update:

I also tried to `require 'omniauth'` in the env.rb file, but I'm not sure that's necessary.

Comment: are you using the omniauth-facebook gem? https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook omniauth will not support facebook on its own, you need a strategy: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies

Comment: The site works great. When I click the button in the browser, it goes to `'/auth/facebook'` and logs me in correctly. So yes, I am using the `facebook-omniauth` gem. Good question.

Comment: I am only concerned with the tests.

Comment: Hi @ardavis , HOW DID YOU SOLVED THIS ISSUE??? PLEASE LET ME KNOW I AM FACING THIS ISSUE SINCE A WEEK.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I ran out of time to work on that project and it has been placed on hold.

Comment: Hey @ardavis - did you ever figure out a solution for this? Am having the same issue.

Comment: I have not solved it, I haven't been working on this project at all. It's been cancelled. If you figure out the solution, please feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem and I solved changing some line in my routes.rb

```
match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: [:get, :post]
```

If your read [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-application) omniauth says to add this line `get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'` in routes.rb but the callback sets the request method to post with a variable called _method.

I hope this help